# Google Stackdriver Logs Viewer: View function execution log entries if trace contains a given string?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

If I query for a string it will only return the specific log entries that contain that string, but I am trying to view the full Cloud Function execution logs where this string is present (e.g., a given customer id).

Currently, I have to click "show entries from this trace" one at a time which is quite cumbersome, especially when I am trying to view multiple traces back to back. Is there any kind of query syntax to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at this [tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-functions-best-practice-4-4-monitor-and-log-the-executions-22222aa25f1b) in monitoring and logging executions. It also shows how to utilize the [stackdriver](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-functions-best-practice-4-4-monitor-and-log-the-executions-22222aa25f1b#:%7E:text=Unleash%20the%20power%20of%20Stackdriver) and run queries.

You can get Cloud Function logs and choose how you want it to be returned:

- Get a specific execution
- Get a specific log
- Get a specific log using regex

Additionally, In [writing advanced queries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/building-queries#queries-by-expression) in the query-editor field, check out the [syntax notation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language#syntax-notation) from the Logging Query Language as it provides an in-depth explanation on how queries are structured. For examples of common queries, see [sample queries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library).